When restricting function arguments using an undefined conditional check, how come the order of the conditional matters?
I wrote a generic TypeScript function that ensures a function accepts either zero or two arguments, but not one. I.e. the second parameter is required if the first argument is passed in.
It looks like this:
function bar<T, P>(a?: undefined extends P ? never : T, b?: P) { }

bar('') // ERROR, as desired.

Initially, I had the conditional type the other way around, but that did not work:
function bar<T, P>(a?: P extends undefined ? never : T, b?: P) { }

bar('') // OK, which it should not be.

If the second argument, i.e. P, is not passed in, then it is undefined, which extends undefined. Therefore, how come P extends undefined does not work?
Playground.

Why would you not just use function overloads?

@jaredSmith I used overloads first, which works. I also made a solution with a rest parameter, which reduces the type complexity to just a union. I decided to go the generic path for learning purposes, as I might need it in more complex scenarios where overloads might not be ideal.

the question has more to do with the fact that generic type P is resolving to unknown, as if you're always using extends on unknown instead of desired P, this behaviour is because b was not provided, P can't resolve into any other type except unknown, if you want an explanation why second example is not throwing error, check this: Playground

You can use spread operator with generic types to solve the problem: Playground

@HairyHandKerchief23 Ah, brilliant. I did not think about the fact that P resolves to unknown. I guess, in terms of "narrow" extends "wide", i.e. "narrow" is assignable to "wide", we could say that unknown is wider than undefined? If we made the type parameters restricted to e.g. string (P extends string), then neither of the two functions would work, because undefined and string are on the same "narrowness" level and cannot be assigned to each other?

@HairyHandKerchief23 Re. the spread, yep, that was actually the second thing I tried (after overloads), but decided not to go with it in real life, as it obscures the function signature from consumers.

@Magnus Typescript's type compatibility establishes that anything is assignable to unknown, that's why undefined extends unknown, but it also establishes that unknown isn't assignable to any type except any, narrow and wide concept has more to do with union types, i forgot to mention that.

@HairyHandKerchief23 Do you know why P resolves to unknown? Should it not resolve to undefined when b is not passed in? Any place in the docs where you read about that behavior?

While one could argue that foo('') should be treated the same as foo('', undefined), TS sees the former as not having any value of type P from which to infer anything (so it fails and falls back to the constraint, which is implicitly unknown) whereas it sees the latter as passing in undefined for a value of type P | undefined and it infers undefined for P. If you want P to fall back to undefined when nothing is passed in, you need to give it a default as shown in this playground link. I could write up an answer if you want, let me know.

@jclaz Yes please, an answer would be great, thank you very much.

The order of the check in a conditional type matters in general, since X extends Y and Y extends X are two different things. This question presumes that P is being inferred as undefined, which would mean both checks were undefined extends undefined, and that would indeed be surprising for there to be a difference. But P is not being inferred as undefined.
What happens with both
function foo<T, P>(a?: P extends undefined ? never : T, b?: P) { }
foo('') // error
function bar<T, P>(a?: undefined extends P ? never : T, b?: P) { }
bar('') // okay

is that no value of type P is being passed in for b, and P cannot be inferred from a. The inference for P therefore completely fails. One might hope or expect that b would be "implicitly" undefined and therefore P would be inferred from undefined, but that's not what happens. Inference just fails.
When type argument inference fails for a generic type parameter, it falls back to its default type argument if one exists, or its constraint if no default exists. Unconstrained type parameters like P have an implicit constraint of unknown.  So what actually happens in both cases is that P is instantiated with unknown.
And since unknown extends undefined is false and undefined extends unknown is true (unknown is the top type in TS; it's a universal supertype) you get different behavior for foo() and bar() there.

If you want inference failure of P to fall back to undefined, you should make undefined the default type argument:
function foo<T, P = undefined>(a?: P extends undefined ? never : T, b?: P) { }
foo(''); // error
function bar<T, P = undefined>(a?: undefined extends P ? never : T, b?: P) { }
bar(''); // error

Now P is undefined in both the above cases, and undefined extends undefined is true in both cases so you get the same behavior.
Playground link to code
